# Make Twitter Bootstrap navbar work like tabs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way to make a navbar (which appears to be designed to link to other pages) behave like a set of nav tabs (which stay on the same page, hiding all but the desired section)?

Actually, my navbar works just as I want, but only if I don't call `$(".nav-tabs").button()`, which I need for other things.  Now none of the collapsing/uncollapsing happens.

Here's the code (which is pretty boiler-plate):

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
 <div class="navbar-inner">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
    <ul id="tab" class="nav">
     <li class="active"><a href="#Tab1" data-toggle="tab">Tab1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#Tab2" data-toggle="tab">Tab2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#Tab3" data-toggle="tab">Tab3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a class="brand" href="#">NavTab Demo</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span12">
   <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="Tab1">
...
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't see any obvious problem in wiring your nav links as tabs.

You just need to ommit tab classes not to override your navbar styles, and don't forget the `data-` attributes (if needed).

Then you have to use the JavaScript activation as specified in the [docs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs) (or use the `data-toggle="tab"` attribute).

Everything should be working.

**Edit** : for posterity, you do need to include ONE of `bootstrap-tab.js` or `bootstrap.js` (or the minified version) and the associated css files too.

Comment: It was, but after adding the nav-tabs.button thingy, it no longer is.  I posted a code sample.

Comment: You were absolutely correct -- and once I included the bootstrap file that the nav-tabs thingy needed, all was well.  Thanks!

Comment: This was most helpful, but any with a normal ul navbar, and also a navbar-right, I end up with "active" items in both sections.