# Twitter Bootstrap Tabbable Navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I'm using twitter bootstrap to create a navbar at the top of my page.  I want the nav elements to work like tabs instead of links.  I see that [others have been able to achieve this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11767214/make-twitter-bootstrap-navbar-work-like-tabs), but I am still not able.

I'm following [this section](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#navbar) of the documents to create a navbar, and the "Tabbable Nav" section [from here](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#navs) to add the tab functionality.

[Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cbgD4/) if you prefer that, but also, here it is pasted here:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Course Manager</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/2.3.2/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">

    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <a class="brand" href="#">Training Courses</a>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li><a href="#courses" data-toggle="tab">Manage Courses</a></li>
          <li><a href="#tools" data-toggle="tab">Manage Tools</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="courses">
        <p>Courses</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tools">
        <p>Tools</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: Does [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/cbgD4/1/) work like you expect it to?

Comment: yes!  what the heck did you even change?  It looks like mine!

Comment: On your original fiddle, expand 'external resources' on the left and click the 'bootstrap.min.js' link. The url in there is not valid so your example wasn't loading the bootstrap javascript file. I simply removed it and then re-added it with a valid url. (note that your angular.js link is broken too.)

Comment: My rage is over 9000.  Would you mind adding an answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your original fiddle, expand 'external resources' on the left and click the 'bootstrap.min.js' link. The url in there is not valid so your example wasn't loading the bootstrap javascript file. I simply removed it and then re-added it with a valid url.