# Tabs in React Bootstrap Navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, tabs, navbar

This is related to [Make Twitter Bootstrap navbar work like tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11767214/make-twitter-bootstrap-navbar-work-like-tabs) But I'm trying to get this working in React.
basically, I'd like tabs to show up in the Nav Bar. Is there an easy way to do that?
 http://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#navigation

```
<Navbar>
  <Navbar.Header>
    <Navbar.Brand>
      <a href="#">React-Bootstrap</a>
    </Navbar.Brand>
  </Navbar.Header>
  <Nav>
    <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">Link</NavItem>
    <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">Link</NavItem>
  </Nav>
</Navbar>
```

In place of NavItem, can I use
 `<Tab eventKey={1} title="Tab 1">Tab 1 content</Tab>`

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
constructor(state) {
        super(state);
        this.state = {
            activeKey: 1
        };
    }

    handleSelect(eventKey) {
        this.setState({
            activeKey: eventKey
        });
    }

render() {

       <Nav bsStyle="tabs" activeKey={this.state.activeKey} 
        onSelect={this.handleSelect.bind(this)}>

        <...>
      }
```

instead of `<Nav>`, it will do the job. [Docs](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#navs-dropdown)